# Desktop on Ubuntu 14.04 lts doesn't appear after login

Tags: command-line, login, login-screen

I have installed `radiotray` and used to start the application from terminal just typing `radiotray`. I wrote a script `start_radio.sh` and put in `/etc/profile.d`. The content of `start_radio.sh` is only

```
radiotray
```

I thought that will automatically run the application on start up.

After restarting my computer, desktop doesn't appear anymore after log in, and here I'm on guest session.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Did you try reverting the changes you made in profile.d? Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and provide us with as much information as possible in order to help us help you. Your original problem could have been easily solved by reviewing http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Comment: Don't know what to sort of information to add more, that all i have done. That link can't solve my question, because i can't se upper taskbar, screen is emtpy, just picture, and that is all.

Comment: How you think to revert it?

Comment: I know what reverting word mind. I ask u how, i explain that there is just picture and that is all

Comment: First, try undoing the changes, maybe remove the start_radiotray.sh , so at least you know how to fix it again if you mess up again. Then if you got the desktop back,  you might want to try specifying full path to radiotray in the script. To find out that , use `which radiotray`.

Comment: Thanks. guys. I first take check does it open terminal with CTRL-ALT-T. And i didn't know for CTRL-F1, @ElderGeek , on my ubuntu, is CTRL-ALT-F1

Comment: @ElderGeek: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)
(and don't forget that there was a time when you didn't know about TTY1-6 neither)  It was back when dinosaurs roamed the Earth and the only silicon we had was rocks, but...  ;-)  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either this is caused by a broken script or an unrelated issue with unity (or both).

If the script is the problem:

Before typing the following keystroke, remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> *is your friend*.  This is the keystroke to type to get back to where you are right now.

OK? Remember? Sure?

Open TTY1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

move radiotray.sh out of /etc/profile.d temporarily to see if it's the problem.

```
mv /etc/profile.d/radiotray.sh ~/Desktop
```

and then reboot

```
sudo shutdown -r 1
```

If this resolves the issue, you can now test your script by running it in it's current location in ~/Desktop. You may find you'll need the full path to radio tray which as @Serg suggests you can obtain with the command `which radiotray`

If this doesn't solve the problem, leave the script where you moved it and continue.

If it's an unrelated Unity problem proceed as follows:

Obtain dconf-tools with

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Next,

```
dconf dump /org/compiz/ > ~/Desktop/myCompizSettings
```

This will dump your Compiz Settings into a file on your Desktop for later review if needed.

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

will reset compiz settings to default.

Finally,

```
setsid unity
```

The above command will restart Unity.

Return to the GUI with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: Prettified...  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the edit I'll paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> into a document so I can remind myself in future..